# Re-assigning moving year values to real months

Tags: r

I have the data.frame with the last 12 months values for 3 observations. There is a Date variable corresponging to the month.m0 (the most recent), and then the values goes backward in time substracting one month each time:

---

```
date <- c("2017-01-01", "2016-12-01", "2016-10-01")
month.m0 <- c(1, 2, 3)
month.m1 <- c(4, 5, 6)
month.m2 <- c(7, 8, 9)
month.m3 <- c(10, 11, 12)
month.m4 <- c(13, 14, 15)
month.m5 <- c(16, 17, 18)
month.m6 <- c(19, 20, 21)
month.m7 <- c(22, 23, 24)
month.m8 <- c(25, 26, 27)
month.m9 <- c(28, 29, 30)
month.m10 <- c(31, 32, 33)
month.m11 <- c(34, 35, 36)

df <- data.frame(date, month.m0, month.m1, month.m2, month.m3, month.m4, month.m5, month.m6, month.m7, month.m8, month.m9, month.m10, month.m11)
```

The input will be:

```
        date month.m0 month.m1 month.m2 month.m3 month.m4 month.m5 month.m6 month.m7 month.m8 month.m9 month.m10 month.m11
1 2017-01-01        1        4        7       10       13       16       19       22       25       28        31        34
2 2016-12-01        2        5        8       11       14       17       20       23       26       29        32        35
3 2016-10-01        3        6        9       12       15       18       21       24       27       30        33        36
```

The problem here is that I don't know the real month of each observation, because the numeration is ordinal and depends on the date variable.

The initial value (month.m0) correspond for the first row to the month january, becasue the date is january (it doesnt matter the day or the year). For the second row, the date is indicating that the **month.m0** corresponds to december, and the third corresponds to october. Then, **month.m1** is the **((month(Date) - months(1))** value, the month.m2 corresponds to **(month(Date) - months(2))** and so on, going back in time from the initial value

EDITED OUTPUT:

I was trying to assign each value to the real month, so the output would be:

```
        date Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1 2017-01-01   1  34  31  28  25  22  19  16  13  10   7   4
2 2016-12-01  35  32  29  26  23  20  17  14  11   8   5   2
3 2016-10-01  30  27  24  21  18  15  12   9   6   3  36  33
```

It's easy to assign the first month for each observation, but then it complicates when going backwards in time.

Comment: Thanks for editing. @Sotos. I was looking for the edit button, then I realised I dont have the priviledge yet...

Comment: You are welcome. However, It is not clear what you mean. Can you try and explain it better? Maybe include any attempts you have made so far

Comment: Updated post with the explanation. Hope it's enough!

Comment: @phariza can you check the last row of your desired output? It doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `df` is the dataframe you provided...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  gather(month_num,value,-date) %>%                                        # reshape datset
  mutate(month_num = as.numeric(gsub("month.m","",month_num)),             # keep only the number (as your step)
         date = ymd(date),                                                 # transform date to date object
         month_actual = month(date),                                       # keep the number of the actual month (baseline)
         month_now = month_actual + month_num,                             # create the current month (baseline + step)
         month_now_upd = ifelse(month_now > 12, month_now-12, month_now),  # update month number (for numbers > 12)
         month_now_upd_name = month(month_now_upd, label=T)) %>%           # get name of the month
  select(date, month_now_upd_name, value) %>%                              # keep useful columns
  spread(month_now_upd_name, value) %>%                                    # reshape again
  arrange(desc(date))                                                      # start from recent month

#         date Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
# 1 2017-01-01   1   4   7  10  13  16  19  22  25  28  31  34
# 2 2016-12-01   5   8  11  14  17  20  23  26  29  32  35   2
# 3 2016-10-01  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36   3   6   9
```

Note that I created various (helpful) variables that you won't need in the end, but they will help you understand the process when you run the chained commands step by step.
You can make the above code shorter by combining some commands within `mutate` if you want.

Comment: Damn, absolutely right, @AntoniosK. I will edit the question to not misunderstand others. Thanks for the answer, it's neat and clear.

Comment: Edited and updated. Your solution was the key to achieve the desired output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is not very clear to me, so my output is not exactly yours. But this is how I would do it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  # First create a new variable containing the month as a numeric between 1-12
  mutate(month = strftime(date, "%m")) %>% 
  # Make data tidy so basically there is new column col containing
  # month.1, month.2, month.3, ... and a column val containg
  # the values
  gather(col, val, -date, -month) %>% 
  # remove "month.m" so the col column has numeric values
  mutate_at("col", str_replace, pattern = "month.m", replacement = "") %>%
  mutate_at(c("month", "col"), as.numeric) %>% 
  # Compute the difference between the month column and the col column
  mutate(col = abs((col - month + 1) %% 12)) %>% 
  # Sort the dataframe according to the new col column
  arrange(month, col) %>% 
  # Add month.m to the col column so we redefine the names of the columns
  mutate(col = paste0("month.m", col), month = NULL) %>% 
  # Untidy the data frame
  spread(col, val)
```

Comment: The output is different because the third row is different from the first and second. My mistake! I will edit it. Thanks!